# Direct dialling from Callback option to be disabled

Tags: asterisk

I am facing 1 issue with my asterisk, When agents make calls directly from there "Callback list" that calls are not recorded. To make call recorded they need to copy number from callback list and dial it manually. Is there any way i can record calls dialed directly from callback list or any way to disable direct dialing from callback list?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you have rewrite your callback application to use recording dialplan or call back via

```
Local/number@from-internal/n
```

Recording of call is not property of call, it have be enabled by dialplan function MixMonitor.

So most likly your callback app just not designed for your pbx or created by stranger in asterisk field.